# Get sum of quantities and update row

Tags: sql, counting

```
`ps_stock_available` (`id_stock_available`, `id_product`, `id_product_attribute`, `id_shop`, `id_shop_group`, `quantity`, `depends_on_stock`, `out_of_stock`) VALUES
(53, 1, 1, 0, 1, 40, 0, 2),
(54, 1, 0, 0, 1, 71, 0, 0),
(55, 1, 2, 0, 1, 31, 0, 2),
(56, 1, 3, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0),
(57, 1, 4, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0),
(58, 1, 5, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0),
(59, 1, 6, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0),
(60, 2, 0, 0, 0, 14, 0, 0),
(61, 2, 0, 0, 1, 14, 0, 0),
(62, 7, 34, 0, 1, 777, 0, 2),
(63, 7, 35, 0, 1, 888, 0, 2),
(64, 6, 0, 0, 1, 14, 0, 0),
(65, 7, 0, 0, 1, 778, 0, 0);

mysql_query('UPDATE `'._DB_PREFIX_.'product_attribute` SET `quantity` = \''.$count.'\' , id_shop = 0 , id_shop_group = 1 WHERE `ean13` = \''.$code.'\' ');

mysql_query('UPDATE `'._DB_PREFIX_.'product` SET `quantity` = \''.$count.'\' WHERE `id_product` = \''.$row->id_product.'\' ');

$id_product_attribute = $row->id_product_attribute;

mysql_query('UPDATE `'._DB_PREFIX_.'stock_available` SET `quantity` = \''.$count.'\' , id_shop = 0 , id_shop_group = 1 WHERE `id_product_attribute` = \''.$id_product_attribute.'\' ');
```

Im updating my stock from XML where are: ean13 code and product quantity.

But I noticed that total quantity is wrong.

(62, 7, 34, 0, 1, 777, 0, 2),
(63, 7, 35, 0, 1, 888, 0, 2)
AND TOTAL quantity:
(65, 7, 0, 0, 1, 778, 0, 0);
It should be not 778 but = 777 + 888 = 1665

How should I write SQL to update this? Count values with same ID and update row with that ID where id_product_attribute = 0.

Comment: You need to be a little clearer in what you are asking for.  Are you using these different matrices to update a table in the DB one after another?  You generally don't want to lose data so I hope you are persisting them somewhere else.

Comment: `mysql_query('UPDATE `'._DB_PREFIX_.'stock_available` SET `quantity` = \''.$count.'\' , id_shop = 0 , id_shop_group = 1 WHERE `id_product_attribute` = \''.$id_product_attribute.'\' ');` 



With this im updating product attribute quantity, but also I need to update total quantity of that product.

`mysql_query('UPDATE `'._DB_PREFIX_.'stock_available` SET `quantity` = COUNT(???) , id_shop = 0 , id_shop_group = 1 WHERE `id_product_attribute` != 0 AND id_product = id_product ');`